# Nativescript ListView very slow with large images

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm presenting a ListView of large images in my app. When i say large, I mean about 4mb each(worked horribly also with smaller ones).

This is my template(notice i'm using Nativescript-Vue):

```
<template>
  <Page class="page">
    <ActionBar class="action-bar">
      <Label class="action-bar-title" text="Hey"></Label>
    </ActionBar>
    <StackLayout>
      <Button @tap="takePicture" text="Take picture"></Button>
      <Button @tap="backup" text="Backup"></Button>
      <Button @tap="openGallery" text="Open gallery"></Button>
      <Button @tap="getAllImages" text="Get all images"></Button>

      <ListView for="image in images">
        <v-template>
          <Image
          class="image"
          :src="image.src"
          />
        </v-template>
      </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
  </Page>
</template>
```

I have this CSS for the image:

```
.image {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 200;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

Visually, this is the result:

[image]

When i scrolldown the images, it's so laggy it's barely usable. **I tried it also on my real device- same issue.** Also i tried playing with the layout and css- the problem persists.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is it a remote image?

Comment: No, the images are from the android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM folder. I'm getting all the src's present in that folder, and just rendering an image for each one.

Comment: Any reason why the images need to be so large for a listview visual? Even compressed and sized smaller you could have a sharp image with high quality and greatly reduced the memory footprint of each image.

Comment: There is no reason for the size. I'm just using the images as they are, created by the camera. How would you load them in smaller size? Would you create a thumbnail, by the app, to represent each image? I'm new to Android, and what bothers me here is that in the browser, a list of 20-30 large images would scroll just fine, even though the browser has no virtualization mechanism.

Comment: With Android you would generally use [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) to list images from Gallery which will also give you a thumbnail path that can be used in ListView.